# knockout.js: input type date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout in UI for my website, i have a problem with input type="date" in Chrome display a Calender but in IE9 just an input type text (empty) 
have some one an idea how to display calender in all browser?

```
 Start: <input type="date" class="required" data-bind="value: StartDate">
```

Thanks,

Comment: With JQuery UI Datepicker... see [Knockout with Jquery UI datepicker][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: @moi_meme Great it's a good example thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input type of "date" is new with HTML5. That's why you're only seeing the calendar with Chrome, you likely have a version of it with HTML5 support included in it. This has nothing to do with knockout.