# knockout wizard + Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, knockout-2.0

I have a wizard contains 4 step with knockout its work fine but when i added  datepicker of Jquery on step 2 date picker doesn't display (just an input type text display) if i refresh my browser it display, but i lose information of step 1 (if i refresh my browser), how can i solve my problem,

my wizard its like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FyuSD/36/

**wizard.cshtml:**

```
....
<script id="step1" type="text/html">    
 <div>Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"></div>
 <div>Description: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"></div>
</script>

<script id="step2" type="text/html">
  Start: <br/><input type="text" id="from"  data-bind="value: StartDate">
  Stop:<br/> <input type="text" id="to" class="required" data-bind="value: EndDate">
</script>
.....
```

**DatePicker.js:**

```
 $(function () {
  $("#from").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
});
```

I'm sorry for my bad English

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with the fiddle a bit and your solution is the answer to this question

[jQuery UI datepicker change event not caught by KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Which shows a datepicker implementation for custom bindings as described in the knockout documentation: [Knockout - Custom Bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

You need to create a custom binding handler that will initialize your datepickers when the template is rendered.

```
    // call this before you call ko.applyBindings()
    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
         init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
             // initialize here
         },
         update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
             // change handler here
         }
    };
```

When you declare your data bindings use the name of your custom binding (instead of "value: StartDate")

```
    <br/>
    Start :<input type="text" id="from" data-bind="datepicker: StartDate, datepickerOptions: {onSelect: $root.onSelectStartDate()}" /> 
    <br/>
    End :<input type="text" id="to" data-bind="datepicker: EndDate, datepickerOptions: {onSelect: $root.onSelectEndDate()}" />
```

Of course `$root` refers to your ViewModel class so that means you need some methods there. This is where you could put your minDate and maxDate code.

```
    function ViewModel() {

        // ...

        self.onSelectStartDate = function() {
            return function() {
                alert("Start Date selected");
            };
        };

        self.onSelectEndDate = function() {
            return function() {
                alert("End Date selected");
            };
        };
    };
```

I tested it in an updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/carbontax/bwA4N/5/. It looks funny because the datepicker css is not available, but the binding handler is doing the right thing.

Comment: i'm added a class to my input like <input classe="uninitialized" ...> and PUBLISH, SUBSCIRIBE code in my datePicker.js but nothing change!

Comment: Where do you insert the templates into the document? You need to make sure that this has completed BEFORE you trigger your custom event

Comment: I edited my code to reflect your script inclusion. I think this is more like what you want. By the way, I like the onSelect handlers, ramo. I think I will use them myself.