# binding a custom event using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using a jQuery UI slider control that raises a change event.  I want to use Knockout to bind to this change event and call a method inside my model.  How is this done?  I am confused, because this event isn't related to the DOM or something that is typically used to bind.

Comment: This is the general pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856112/using-knockout-js-with-jquery-ui-sliders

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an event listener that sets the model variable, ie

```
 var callback = function(value) { 
    koModel.someVariable(value);
 }
```

and use that as the callback to your slider.