# Jquery ui slider with knockoutjs,how to use the change event on view model

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

How do you access the **change event** for a slider when using knockoutjs.I have created a custom binding for the slider like from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856112/using-knockout-js-with-jquery-ui-sliders)
    .For example this is what I would like to do:

```
<div data-bind="slider: minMax, sliderOptions: {min: 20, max: 500, range: 'min', step: 50, values: [20 , 50 ]},sliderChange:DoSomethingWithNewValues" />
```

I would like to have a binding like **sliderChange** that only happens when the slider **change event** happens and would like to call the viewModel method DoSomethingWithNewValues.

```
  function myViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.minMax = ko.observable([20, 50]);
        self.DoSomethingWithNewValues = function(){
          //make ajax stuff etc with new values
        }
  }
```

Or is there a better way to solve this problem. I do not want to use the event handling like this

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   change: function( event, ui ) {
     //somehow call myViewModel.DoSomethingWithNewValues ();
     //outside of my view model
   }
});
```

I have already tried

```
this.minMax.subscribe(function(newminMax) {
   //call myViewModel.DoSomethingWithNewValues ();
  //this causes it to be called several times if you hover without sliding the slider like 
  //there is bug or something          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom binding is attaching a handler to the `slide` event (like from your fiddle), then the observable's value will be updated while the user is sliding. One option is to change the custom binding to only attach to the `change` event, then subscribe to your observable the way that you had previously tried.

Otherwise, if you could even avoid the extra `sliderChange` option in your binding and just add it in the `sliderOptions` as: `change: myHandler`.

Comment: Thanks I have tried it with the event change in the binding..same thing happening with the strange effect on hover (not the draging of the slider)...maybe let me try the change:myhandler but now I cant pass in eg $parent.DoSomethingWithNewValues it breaks

Comment: my mistake for some strange reason I was mixing up the access using $parent...its working perfectly thanks btw RP Niemeyer thanks for http://www.knockmeout.net/ I enjoy reading your posts :) helps a lot