# Why I am unable to call this JavaScript function with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to call this function "CallAgain()" from click of a button but I am unable to do so. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong? The second button with data-bind is working fine.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="slid" data-bind="attr: {min: 1, max: MaxPage}, value: CurrPage" type="range"  data-highlight="true">
<hr/>
X1=<span data-bind="text: CurrPage"></span></br>
X2=<span data-bind="text: MaxPage"></span>
<hr>
<button onclick="alert(x1);">Call Again</button>
<button data-bind="click: changeCurrent">Change current</button>
```

And here is JS code:

```
var x1 = 8,
    x2 = 10;

function CallAgain() {

    alert("AAA");
    var vm = new AppViewModel();
    //if ( FirstRun == true ) ko.applyBindings(vm);
    x1++;
    x2++;
    vm.CurrPage(x1);
    vm.MaxPage(x2);
    vm.changeCurrent(); 
    FirstRun = false;

}



function ViewModel () {
    this.CurrPage = ko.observable(x1);
    this.MaxPage = ko.observable(x2);

    this.CurrPage.subscribe(function (value) {
        x1 = value;
    });

    this.changeCurrent = function () {
        x1++;
        x2++;
        this.CurrPage(x1);
        this.MaxPage(x2);
        alert( this.CurrPage() );
        $('#slid').slider("refresh");
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/497/)

Thanks

**Update-1**

here is the revised [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/500/)

ChangeCurrent button, which calls changeCurrent() function directly, does update x1 & x2 values in DOM but Call Again button doesn't change them. The second problem is that the slider doesn't update although it has its attributes data-bound.

Any advice please?

Comment: You're not using *knockout* in the "onclick" code. For that reason, the variable x1 isn't available in the scope where alert is running

Comment: But alert("AAA") should work at least?

Comment: And if I comment out the last row and instead uncomment this one [if ( FirstRun == true ) ......] then everything stops working.

Comment: Your alert(x1); doesn't work because x1 is undefined. There is no x1 in global scope as you declare it in onDomready function. The same for CallAgain.

Comment: So what should I do? Enclosing that within $(document).ready(function(){  } doesn't work

Comment: Can you please update the jsfiddle code and guide?

Comment: All you need to do in the fiddle is change the onDomReady dropdown to nowrap.  Alternatively, you could remove the var before x1 and x2 so that they're added to the global namespace but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thanks @DoctorMick. Please see the Update-1 above and advise. Thx

Comment: Well that took a while to spot! :)  You're binding a one instance of a view model and then setting vm to another instance. See: http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/501/

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure the knockout value binding works with a range input (could be wrong).  You can use the jquery ui slider with a custom binding tho: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856112/using-knockout-js-with-jquery-ui-sliders

Comment: Thanks. It works with range input. However the only issue that I am now facing is that the slider doesn't automatically refresh itself. And I do not want to use  binder."refresh" because it causes flicker which was the only reason why I started exploring knockout.

Comment: In fact if I change "no wrap" to "onLoad" then the binding starts. However in that case "Call Again" doesn't work and the slider's pointer doesn't refresh, despite the changing value. What can be the reason? Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/502/