# Can’t seem to access any parameters except allBindings in custom binding within event registered with registerEventHandler

Tags: knockout-3.0, cropperjs

I have a knockout custom binding that wraps functionality to an image crop library (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper .)  I’m catching the cropend.cropper event to (eventually) attach the cropped output to an observable.

I’m using:

- knockout 3.3
- jquery 2.1.4
- cropper 2.0

Here is the binding handler:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.cropper = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            var a = 1;
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "cropend.cropper", function (event) {
                var previewOutputObservable = allBindings.get('previewOutput');
                var valueAccessorFromAllBindings = allBindings.get('cropper');
                var b = 1;
            });
            $element.cropper(value);
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            var c = 1;
        }
    };
```

And here is the element I'm binding to:

```
<img class="img-responsive" data-bind="attr: {'src': sampleObservable}, cropper: { aspectRatio: 16/9 }, previewOutput: cropPreview "/>
```

When I put a breakpoint (in chrome) on `var b = 1`; none of the parameters in the init are defined except allBindings.   I’ve seen several examples use this general pattern though (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18331650/1483246)).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer variables are accessible through a closure context. Chrome tries to optimize the context by only including variables that are actually accessed in the closure code. Since `element` wasn't accessed in your code, it's not part of the context. This is a good feature as it means that variables that aren't used in any closure can be safely disposed.

Answer (score 0):

This is either an issue with the Chrome debugging tools or a 'feature' of knockout.

Before `var b = 1` I added the line `var newValue = element`.  I put a breakpoint on that line and lo and behold the element parameter now has values.

It seems like the variables aren't initialized until they're used in the current context.