# how to use datepicker with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Knockout with Jquery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker)

I using knockout.js and jquery datepicker plugin. My code :

```
   <form id="editCForm">
            <table class="ui-widget">
                <tbody data-bind="with: selectedCeremony">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="editDate">Date</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Date" id="editDate" name="Date" class="uidate" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".uidate").datepicker();
```

The problem is that the datepicker plugin is not working on the input file in which knockout.js bindings are applied. I am absolutly new with knockout.js. Please help me?

Comment: Look here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker