# BindingHandlers on my input with knockout not correctly interpreted

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I work on a website with the durandal template.

I have this bindingHandlers for my dates:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();  // 'Mon Sep 10 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))'; 
        var date = moment(value());
        $(element).val((date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')));
    }
};
```

Here is the call in my view:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-bind="date: demandDate" />
```

This is used for formatting my dates in the correct format. It works I mean my date is correctly formatted in my input field.

But **the problem is that whenever the date is modified in the input field, the system did not detect any change.**

If I replace the 'date' by 'value' it is correctly interpreted when the value changed but I miss formatting:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-bind="value: demandDate" />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `update:` of the binding handler is fired after `valueHasMutated()` is issued from the `knockout.js` `ViewModel`. If you want to correctly apply changes to the `ViewModel` from your custom `bindingHandler` then you need to create an event handler in `init:` for the change event of the  input and then issue a change to the `ViewModel`.

Example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function (event) {
            valueAccessor().demandDate($(element).val());
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();  // 'Mon Sep 10 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))'; 
        var date = moment(value());
        $(element).val((date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me an orientation. A complete solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Wouldn't valueAccessor()($(element).val()); make more sense than valueAccessor().demandDate($(element).val()); to make this binding more reusable?