# Knockout change while jQuery Datepicker is open breaks Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, datepicker

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neonms92/DNwLF/) to demonstrate my problem.

**What I'm doing**:

I'm using `Knockout` with a `jQuery` `Datepicker` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker).

My model contains an `observableArray` which contains objects with date properties. Knockout renders an `<input type="text">` for every object, and binds the value to the date using RP Niemeyer's `datepicker` binding.

**What's going wrong:**

If the user has a datepicker open when knockout's model changes (e.g., adding a new item), the datepicker stops working correctly. From what I can tell, the last `<input type="text">` created while the datepicker is open becomes the new datepicker target. **I need to fix the binding so that this does not happen**.

**Sample HTML**:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: dateBoxes">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: index"></span>
        <input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: date"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Sample Javascript**:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        //handle date data coming via json from Microsoft
        if (String(value).indexOf('/Date(') == 0) {
            value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
        }

        var current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};

var model;
var id = 0;
function DateBox(d) {
    var self = this;
    self.date = ko.observable(d);
    self.index = ko.observable(id++);
}
function Model() {
    var self = this;
    self.dateBoxes = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.changeCount = function() {
        if (self.dateBoxes().length < 2) {
            self.dateBoxes.push(new DateBox(new Date()));
        } else if (self.dateBoxes().length > 1) {
            self.dateBoxes.splice(0,1);
        }
    }
    self.tick = function() {
        self.changeCount();
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.tick();
        }, 5000);
    }
    self.tick();
}
model = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer isn't complete. However, as it's too large for a comment and probably helpful (towards a solution) anyhow I've taken the liberty and posted it as an answer. Anyone that can complete this answer is invited to do so through an edit or by spinning off into another better answer.

---

The thing that seems to be spoiling the party (taken [from the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), emphasis mine):

> This will be called **once when the binding is first applied** to an element, and again whenever the associated observable changes value.

If I hackisly prevent the `update` from doing its `datepicker` calls in the *first* update the datepicker won't break anymore (other issues do arise though). For the `init` I've added this line at the end:

```
element.isFirstRun = true;
```

Then the `update` method will do the following just before the `datepicker` calls:

```
if (element.isFirstRun) {
    $(element).val(value);
    element.IsFirstRun = false;
    return;
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/DNwLF/15/) for the results, which are:

- the mentioned scenario now updates the correct textbox (a good thing);
- the initial value is now a more verbose DateTime string and stays that way after updates (kinda not nice);

Hopefully this will help towards a more complete solution.

Comment: I didn't see it at first, but I think you got it. You can fix the datetime string by using the datepicker to format the value before writing to the element. http://jsfiddle.net/DNwLF/58/ If you update your answer I'll accept it.