# Why I can't use datepicker twice in the same table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know that there are simmilar questons, but I really can't find an answer fitting on my issue.

I have this `HTML` table witch is looping trough an array - defined in my viewModel:

```
<div class="formElement" id="AssimilationDT" style="overflow-x: auto; width: 100em;">           
               <table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3</th>
        <th> 4</th>
        <th> 5</th>
        <th> 6</th>
        <th> 7</th>
        <th> 8</th>
        <th> 9</th>
        <th> 10</th>
        <th> 11</th>
        <th> 12/th>
        <th> 13</th>
        <th> 14</th>
        <th> 15</th>
        <th> 16</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: assimilationRows">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="AssimilationDate" id="AssimilationDate" data-bind="event: { mouseover: assimilationDatePicker}, value: AssimilationDate"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="InvoiceSum" data-bind="value: InvoiceSum"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondAssimAmm" data-bind="value: FondAssimAmm"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondSgebFondPerc" data-bind="value: FondSgebFondPerc"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondWholeAssimPerc" data-bind="value: FondWholeAssimPerc"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SgebAssimAmm" data-bind="value: SgebAssimAmm"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SgebFondSgeb" data-bind="value: SgebFondSgeb"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SgebWholeAssimPerc" data-bind="value: SgebWholeAssimPerc"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondSuppl" data-bind="value: FondSuppl"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondSupplNum" data-bind="value: FondSupplNum"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondSupplInvNum" data-bind="value: FondSupplInvNum"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="FondDesc" data-bind="value: FondDesc"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SgebSuppl" data-bind="value: SgebSuppl"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SgebSupplNum" data-bind="value: SgebSupplNum"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SgebSupplInvNum" data-bind="value: SgebSupplInvNum"></td>
        <td>
                <img src="/HDSHubCreditMonitoring/js/images/close.jpg" alt="Close" data-bind="click: $root.removeAssimilationRow"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="newSupplierRow" class="button" data-bind="click: newAssimilationRow">Добави Ред</button>
           </div>
```

what I have in my viewModel is the below code - containing the table rows and it is supposed to execute the `.datepicker`:

```
AssimilationInfo = function(clientNum){
                    this.AssimilationDate = null;
                    this.InvoiceSum = null;
                    this.FondAssimAmm = null;
                    this.FondSgebFondPerc = null;
                    this.FondWholeAssimPerc = null;
                    this.SgebAssimAmm = null;
                    this.SgebFondSgeb = null;
                    this.SgebWholeAssimPerc = null;
                    this.FondSuppl = null;
                    this.FondSupplNum = null;
                    this.FondSupplInvNum = null;
                    this.FondDesc = null;
                    this.SgebSuppl = null;
                    this.SgebSupplNum = null;
                    this.SgebSupplInvNum = null;
                    this.SgebDesc = null;
                    assimilationDatePicker = (function() {
                        $( "#AssimilationDate" ).datepicker({
                            yearRange: "-20:+100",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                        });
                    });
                },
```

AND

```
newAssimilationRow = function (){
                      this.assimilationRows.push(new AssimilationInfo(this.clientNumber()));
                  },

                  removeAssimilationRow = function (ca){
                      assimilationRows.remove(ca);
                  },
```

The above functions are adding, or removing a rows in the HTML table.
The problem I'm facing is that the `.datepicker` is working only on the 1st table row - if I add another row, it is just not working.

I'm pretty sure that I can't call it correctly, but I'm not able to spot the issue as a beginner. Is there a way to call the `datepicker` on every table row?

**UPDATE**

I added

```
assimilationDatePicker = (function() {
                        $( ".AssimilationDate" ).datepicker({
                            yearRange: "-20:+100",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                        });
                    });
```

and now it shows on every row, but only the value of the 1st row input is updated.

Comment: because you creating datepicker for id: `$( "#AssimilationDate" ).datepicker`, thy to add class selector: `$( ".AssimilationDate" ).datepicker` and in form also `<td><input type="text" name="AssimilationDate" id="AssimilationDate" class="AssimilationDate" data-bind="event: { mouseover: assimilationDatePicker}, value: AssimilationDate"></td>`

Comment: @krasu it worked, but, now it updates only the value of the 1st box :(

Comment: `assimilationDatePicker = ...` - is global objcet, try this `this.assimilationDatePicker = ...`, I don't have expertise with knockout.js, so don't sure it will help

Comment: still the same. Thanks for trying to help me!!!

Comment: any chance to have jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Have u solved problem??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are facing after update is in using same id for all your datepickers. You should remove id from datepicker element and then jquery-ui will generate it automatically and everything will work. I've modified a bit jsbin code of [@Kishorevarma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631198/1001278) to demonstrate [it](http://jsbin.com/UgELONO/3/).

---

Also, I recommend you to use custom binding for datepicker, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-event-not-caught-by-knockoutjs) is good example of it.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
            $el = $(element);

        $el.datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $el.datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element);

        //handle date data coming via json from Microsoft
        if (String(value).indexOf('/Date(') == 0) {
            value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
        }

        var current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

Then you'll just need to replace your input with

```
<input data-bind="datepicker: myDate, datepickerOptions: {
                        yearRange: "-20:+100",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                    }" />
```

This is much cleaner and more readable than using mouseover event.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `datepicket` using `ID`, it will work for only one element. You need to set a common class for the elements, which needs to show a datepicket, something like below

suppose, you set the `class` like `class="datepicketTxt"`

then call the `datepicker` like this

```
                    $( ".datepicketTxt").datepicker({
                        yearRange: "-20:+100",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                    });
```

Comment: The problem is that it updates only the value of the 1st row :(

Comment: when I click on the input box, no matter the row, only the value in the first row is updated and the otehr rows are remaining empty.

Comment: can you try to move you `datepicker` call to `$(document).ready` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question's answer is quite obvious one i am explaining my answer by giving example you have one element and one jquery like this one

```
<input type="text" name="AssimilationDate" id="AssimilationDate" data-bind="event: { mouseover: assimilationDatePicker}, value: AssimilationDate">
```

right? now if you see that your id is **AssimilationDate** But problem is that one control have one unique id per page so this can not be possible

now what to do? i am taking two inputs now

```
<input type="text" name="AssimilationDate" id="AssimilationDate" class="Assimilation" data-bind="event: { mouseover: assimilationDatePicker}, value: AssimilationDate">


 <input type="text" name="AssimilationDate1" class="Assimilation"  id="AssimilationDate1" data-bind="event: { mouseover: assimilationDatePicker}, value: AssimilationDate">
```

and your javascript function will looks like this one

```
assimilationDatePicker = (function() {
                        $( ".Assimilation" ).datepicker({
                            yearRange: "-20:+100",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            dateFormat: "d-M-y"
                        });
                    });
```

This is only for two controls you can multiply it n times using class so if one control you want to use then just use id and if multiple then use same class in multiple ids
i hope this will help to get your solution regards....

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will solve your problem for sure. I have written a sample code here

```
 http://jsbin.com/UgELONO/2/edit
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There can only be a single ID per page, which must be unique, use a class as the selector for multiple elements when applying datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

Change the content of the function "assimilationDatePicker" to

```
   $(arguments[1].target).datepicker({
                yearRange: "-20:+100",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "d-M-y"
            });
```

You can read up on the document here regarding the arguments passed when you use the Event binding

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

use different 
`<script></script>`
 tag for every call.