# check the date and if it is less than a month from today display some content using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have an input field that asks user to pick a date and if the date is less than 30 days form today it will display some other contents.  I am using jQueryUI datapicker and knockout.js for data binding and here is what I have so far [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srabeat/78a1rL7q/) but it's not working. What am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.request_due_date = ko.observable();
    self.request_due_date_rush = ko.observable(false);
    self.request_due_date_rush_reason = ko.observable();

    self.request_due_date.subscribe(function(dd) {
      var cur = new Date(),
        rush_date = cur.setDate(cur.getDate() + 30);
      if (dd < rush_date) {
        self.request_due_date_rush(true);
      }
    });
  };
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

```html
<div>Due Date:
  <input id="datepicker" data-bind="text: request_due_date" type="text" />
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: request_due_date_rush">Reason For Rush:
  <input data-bind="text: request_due_date_rush_reason" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `value`, not `text`.

```
<input id="datepicker" data-bind="value: request_due_date" type="text" />
```

Also the value `dd` is a string and must be parsed to date, for example using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var days = moment().diff(moment(dd, "MM/DD/YYYY"), "days");
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78a1rL7q/12/)

Comment: if you change the condition to (days < 30 ) it will work but not correctly. It updates the DOM for pretty much any date

Comment: @Saeed You are right, the mistake was in days count and date format. updated fiddle

Comment: I think I figured it out (with your help). I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's because when you create the datepicker object, the underlying input element gets moved around in the DOM, breaking the binding. Consider writing your own binding handler, like seen here:
[jQuery UI datepicker change event not caught by KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-event-not-caught-by-knockoutjs)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MaxBrodin for the insight (to bind `value`, not `text`) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) I found the following solution to be working. Here is also the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srabeat/78a1rL7q/13/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.request_due_date = ko.observable();
    self.request_due_date_rush = ko.observable(false);
    self.request_due_date_rush_reason = ko.observable();

    self.request_due_date.subscribe(function(dd) {
      var date1 = new Date(dd);
      var date2 = new Date();
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
      var days = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

      self.request_due_date_rush(days < 30);
    });
  };
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

```html
<div>Due Date:
  <input id="datepicker" data-bind="value: request_due_date" type="text" />
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: request_due_date_rush">Reason For Rush:
  <input data-bind="text: request_due_date_rush_reason" />
</div>
```