# Knockout binding for datepicker with dynamic options

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using knockout binding for jQuery date picker.

Refer to [jQuery UI datepicker change event not caught by KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-event-not-caught-by-knockoutjs)

The same code is working fine except I can't set datepicker options dynamically.

How to set datepicker option (like mindate max date etc) dynamically (button click) using the the above reference link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to make the `options` object part of your view-model. Then, upon changes, update the `datePicker` with the new `options`.

This way, you can add any of the [options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (like `dayNames` and `dateFormat` etc) to your `options` object, and the binding handler will update the component automatically.

For example (changing `minDate` dynamically):

```
var viewModel = {
    myDate: ko.observable(new Date("12/01/2013")),
    setToCurrentDate: function() {
        this.myDate(new Date());
    },
    options: {
        // make sure you're using an observable to wrap the value
        minDate: ko.observable(new Date()) 
    },
    changeMinDate: function(){
        this.options.minDate(new Date('01/01/2015'));
    }
};
```

And in the binding-handler (adding subscription to changes on `options`):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $el = $(element);
        var opts = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions;

        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = ko.mapping.toJS(opts) || {};
        $el.datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $el.datepicker("destroy");
        });

        // subscribe to all changes in the options object
        ko.computed(function(){
            var options = ko.mapping.toJS(opts) || {};

            for (var i in options)
                $el.datepicker('option', i, options[i]);
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element),
            current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.datepicker("setDate", value);   
        }
    }
};
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAgNV/1860/)