# Twitter Bootstrap not working inside a div that is bind to an observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I want to implement twitter bootstrap in my textbox but It's not working because when I implement it inside in a div "with" binding in knockout.

```
 <div class="container" data-bind="with: itemForEditing">   
             <input type="text" class="input-large custom form_date" data- bind="text:AuditDate" />
 </div>
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question and Ramon wants to get date picker to work with knockout. You need to take advantage of knockout binding handlers in such case which has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121960/bootstrap-datepicker-with-knockout-js-databind