# Bootstrap datepicker not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Bootstrap datepicker is not working after ajax call.

On First time load page its working properly but after ajax call I am just updaing 'data-date-start-date' and 'data-date-end-date' attribute value by knockout js.

Also there is no any error display on inspect element of browser.

Here is my code:

```js
 function MEI() {

        var self = this;
        self.TranDate = ko.observable();
      
        self.StartDate = ko.observable();
        self.EndDate = ko.observable();
        self.StartDate("04/01/2016");
        self.EndDate("04/30/2016");

        self.TranDate("04/22/2016")
        self.ChangeDate = function()
        {

            var date = new Date();
            var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 3 - 1, 1);
            var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 3, 0);
            var sd = ((firstDay.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + firstDay.getDate() + '/' + firstDay.getFullYear());
            var ed = ((lastDay.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + lastDay.getDate() + '/' + lastDay.getFullYear());

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Home")',
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                data: '',
                success: function (result) {
                    self.TranDate("");
                    self.StartDate(sd);
                    self.EndDate(ed);
                    //$(".test").attr('data-date-start-date',sd);
                    //$(".test").attr('data-date-end-date',ed);

                },
                error: function (errorThrown) {
                }
            });
        }
       
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new MEI());
    });
```

```html
<tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="test" type="text" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker test" data-bind="value:TranDate, attr:{'data-date-start-date':StartDate ,'data-date-end-date':EndDate}"  data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" readonly />
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <button type="submit" data-bind="click:ChangeDate">Click</button>
                    </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datepicker with knockout.js databind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121960/bootstrap-datepicker-with-knockout-js-databind)

Comment: You should really be using a custom binding to interact with jQuery plugins. When you have two things manipulating the DOM, its easy for them to get out of sync. An example is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121960/bootstrap-datepicker-with-knockout-js-databind