# knockout js bind with datetimepicker gives an exception

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I think I can easily bind a date data with jquery ui calendar and knockout.js thanks to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400701/1194873)

Now I need to bind a date data as well as its time. Of course, I can use [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). But I am not sure how I can bind its data with knockout.js. I expected it'd be similar to datepicker so I made following script

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datetimepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datetimepicker(options);

            //handle the field changing
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));//****
            });

            //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).datetimepicker("destroy");
            });

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                current = $(element).datetimepicker("getDate");

            if (value - current !== 0) {
                $(element).datetimepicker("setDate", value);
            }
        }
    };
```

But when I ran the script, I get an error in line of `//****` in javascript

```
TypeError: observable is not a function
```

But I can't find what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found following code is working. As few open source code do, this addon is not very stable and will call change event with null observable sometimes. So I made the code to catch the exception and move on.

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datetimepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datetimepicker(options);

            //handle the field changing
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                try {
                    observable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));//****
                }
                catch(ex) {}
            });

            //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).datetimepicker("destroy");
            });

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                current = $(element).datetimepicker("getDate");

            if (value - current !== 0) {
                $(element).datetimepicker("setDate", value);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

This particular error is due to the observable = valueAccessor() line.  You are assigning to observable the value of valueAccessor by adding the () to the end.  In order to pass a value to observable in this way, you would need to write instead:

```
var observable = valueAccessor;
```

Otherwise, observable is not an 'observable function'.

Comment: You are right. It's working now. But the reason why the same code worked for datepicker is the thing I don't understand.

Comment: I just find out that your answer is wrong. valueAccessor() should give the correct knockout observalue. If I use what you suggested `valueAccessor`, the control will never work!

Comment: This answer is half correct: the [documentation specifically does what OP does](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#modifying-observables-after-dom-events). However, it depends on how the binding was defined (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18015621).

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line

```
var observable = valueAccessor();
```

With

```
var xxxx= valueAccessor();
```

Because you cannot use the observable, because it is reserved keyword in knockout.

Also, you may get error somewhere in future if you use observable as variable name.

Comment: This makes no sense. Reserved keywords is a javascript feature, not a knockoutjs feature, moreover this concerns a limited scoped variable, which would have no impact on existing global variables of the same name.