# using JQueryUI DateTimePicker with Knockout

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, datetimepicker

In Continuation of 
[knockout js bind with datetimepicker gives an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832589/knockout-js-bind-with-datetimepicker-gives-an-exception)
I am now able to use the datetimepicker with knockout but I am unable to use the time picker option of the same tool the code I have tried is embedded into the following jsfiddle but is throwing an error

```
<code>
http://jsfiddle.net/saqibshakil/scdET/
</code>
```

check console after edit

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Your fiddle is 2000 lines long. Ain't nobody got time for that.

Comment: Tyrius the fiddle is that long because i used the datetimepicker library and as there were no cdn for it i had to paste it in the javascript i will try and find a host

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTimezoneOffset'

This is the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like calling `getDate` on `timepicker` does not return an actual `Date`.

It appears that you can call it using `datetimepicker` successfully.  So, your binding would look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.timepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize timepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().timepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).timepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).timepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    //update the control when the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            current = $(element).datetimepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datetimepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

Updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/L3BNw/