# Knockout wrap value binding

Tags: knockout.js

I am using [mathias bynen's placeholder code](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) and I wanted to use it along with knockout, if I do a simple custom binding like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.placeholder = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).placeholder();
    }
};
```

and the html

```
<input placeholder = "Line 1" data-bind="placeholder: {}, value: addressLine1">
```

It works, but I would like to "merge" them into one custom binding, for using it like

```
<input placeholder = "First Name" data-bind="placeholderValue: firstName">
```

So I tried this code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.placeholderValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).placeholder();
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

but it raises me an

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm not really getting the grip of ko yet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are creating a delegating custom binding as a best practice you should always pass [all the arguments](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) of the `init` and `update` to the inner bindings, because you can never know what parameters the inner binding uses:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.placeholderValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                    viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).placeholder();
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, 
             allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                     viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, 
             allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

You have got the exception because the `init` of the `value` biding uses the `allBindingsAccessor` parameter but because you haven't passed that in it raises the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nemesv, didn't know that and actually I have been messing my code these days because I couldn't work out similar solutions for other scenarios. At least it was soon enough that you told me this to change them

Comment: Thanks. 1 small change that may help others: I needed to wrap the placeholder call in a timeout setTimeout(function(){ $(element).placeholder();},0) in order for the code to work with valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'