# Knockoutjs and JQuery datepicker. Element looses datepicker after re-render

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

When i'm trying to use input with id "eventStartDate", after it was hidden, and made visible again - it looses datepicker:

```
<!-- ko 'if': isEvent.forEditing -->
    <div class="editor-field">
        <div class="editor-label">Початок події: </div>
        <input type="datetime" name="eventStartDate" id="eventStartDate" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eventStartDate)
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Can somebody tell me how to force $("#eventStartDate").datepicker() init this object after it was re rendered?

Thank you.

UPD: i know that it must be done through custom bindings somehow, but can somebody help me to figure out, how exactly?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best idea is to consider using a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) like the one in this answer: [knockoutjs databind with jquery-ui datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399078/knockoutjs-databind-with-jquery-ui-datepicker/6400701#6400701) or this answer: [jQuery UI datepicker change event not caught by KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612705/knockout-with-jquery-ui-datepicker/6613255#6613255).

If you don't need the two-way data-binding, then a minimal custom binding would be simply:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
   init: function(element) {
       $(element).datepicker();

       //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
       ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
       });
   }  
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) That works. I'll try to study custom binds a bit more.