# Maximum value on Knockout Datepicker

Tags: knockout.js

```
 <td>
     <input id="dt_dec_date" data-bind="datepicker: vm.afi.Details.DecisionDate" />
 </td>

 DecisionDate: ko.observable(),
```

I need to ensure that the date is not more than today, I have tried using max but cant get it to work, any ideas.

Sorry if this is really simple but I ma new to knockout. I have this value coming from a server but the user is allowed to change it but can't go beyond todays date.

Comment: You need to show us the custom binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavily inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400701/2571926). Suppose, that you're using `datepicker` binding from that mentioned answer, then you just need to use the following markup:

```
<input id="dt_dec_date" data-bind="datepicker: decisionDate, datepickerOptions: { maxDate: new Date() }" />
```

And view model is:

```
var viewModel = {
    ...
    decisionDate: ko.observable(new Date("08/15/2014")),
    ...
};
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewLmh7hf/).