# how to handle date for posting purposes in the server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, knockout.js, momentjs

I have this value from ASP.NET MVC `/Date(1446393600000)/` which its value in SQL Database is `'2015-11-02'` which is a `date` (date only) and to manipulate it as javascript object, I used [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), so when used as `moment('/Date(1446393600000)/')` I got this result `"2015-11-01T16:00:00.000Z"`

And so this code:

The bindingHandler can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400701/1214293)

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
        $el = $(element);

    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    $el.datepicker(options);

    //handle the field changing
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable(moment($el.datepicker("getDate"))); // I added moment function here
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $el.datepicker("destroy");
    });

  }
  /*,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        $el = $(element),
        current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

      if (value - current !== 0) {
        $el.datepicker("setDate", value);
      }
    }*/
};
  
var vm = {
  sampleDate: ko.observable(moment('/Date(1446393600000)/')), // I added moment function here
  originalValue: '/Date(1446393600000)/', // For reference only
  FromSqlDb: '2015-11-02' // For reference only
};

vm.formattedDate = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.sampleDate() ? 
    this.sampleDate().format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY") :
  '';
}, vm);
 

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: sampleDate" /> <br />
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

As you can see, the value `2015-11-02` is now converted to **UTC** `"2015-11-01T16:00:00.000Z"` when I used `moment()` on it. Which is I don't want, since I want to retain what I have got from the db

So my question is:

1. Does momentjs always convert your date to its utc?
2. When I try to `post` the `sampleDate`I got this error. [image]

My temporary solution is to `post` the `computed` variable. (`formattedDate` and it works)

Please help me understand why the error occur. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The date is what you chose. Use moment's `toDate` and you'll get a js Date object which has the expected value. What you see is the UTC representation, i.e. the same hour translated to the Z zone (meridian 0, or Greenwrich meridian).
2. Accordint to the OP comment, the date is posted by using `.toISOString()`. In this case, if you're in a time zone other than Z (Greenwich meridian), the date will refer to the previous date. For example the date `2015-04-20 GMT+1`, will be formatted as `2015-04-19T23:00:00.000Z`, and the server will clip the time and time zone info, so it will get one day before the desired day.

To avoid the problem in 2. we can instruct moment to parse the date as if it was an UTC date, like this:  `moment.utc('datestring')`. For example, doing `moment.utc('2015-03-11')` will create the date `2015-03-11T00:00:00.000Z`, so the covnersion to ISO string will give the desired date. In this instance, you have to change this line of code:

```
observable(moment($el.datepicker("getDate")))
```

to

```
observable(moment.utc($el.datepicker("getDate")))
```

Comment: for #1, am I right, that if the date has `Z` at the end is represented as UTC based on ISO-8601 format? #2 I tried using `toDate` but ended posting the minimum value of the date, instead i used `toISOString`. What do you think?

Comment: If you use `toISOString`, the date is represented in time zone Z. And, unless you make a custom binder ASP.NET MVC simplty takes the date without taking into account the time zone. For any country in the east of that time zone (western Europe, except Portugal and UK) will get the date of the date before. You could try to correct this by using moment `.utcOffset` before posting. But this would lead to problems if you started to use the date and time parts.

Comment: Yes. But I won't be needing the time portion since I only need to store `date` and date only. Im round tripping a calendar date. What I retrieve from the database will be the same value of what it will appear on the page. No converting. What options do I have? Since `toDate()` will give me minimum date value. Will `toISOString` do?

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide you an easier solution