# how to convert utc datetime to Fuzzy Time stamps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, knockout.js

I have a post action method which properly saves data into database along with date in utc date format.
Now, i have a get method which fetches all the data from database in proper format like this:

```
  public JsonResult GetPosts()
    {
        var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = post.Message,
                       PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                       PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                       PostedByAvatar = _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(post.PostedBy),
                       PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                       PostId = post.PostId,
                 });
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

now, i have added getTimeAgo plugin from nuget packages and added to script folder.
In my Scripts folder, i have a wallpost.js file which contains client side models for updating model and client side view model for updating UI automatically.
here, i have a getTimeAgo function to get fuzzy time stamps from utc datetime.
It is something like this:

```
   function getTimeAgo(varDate) {
if (varDate) {
    return $.timeago(varDate.toString().slice(-1) == 'Z' ? varDate : varDate + 'Z');
}
else {
    return '';
}
```

}
**But on the view page, its simply displaying NaNyearsAgo**.As i have said earlier, date is saved in proper format in database but i am unable to convert utc date time to fuzzy time stamps.
I have uploaded my entire wallpost.js file here for increasing brevity.http://pastebin.com/VVUuMScL
On my View Page, I am showing post with user's image like this:

```
        <ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
<li class="postHolder">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }" width="150" height="200">

    <p><a data-bind="text: PostedByName"></a>: <span data-bind=" html: Message"></span></p>
    <div class="postFooter">
        <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: PostedDate"></span>&nbsp;<a class="linkComment" href="#" data-bind=" click: toggleComment">Comment</a>

    </div>
</li>
```

Please suggest me what is going wrong.

Comment: Use a decent library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Comment: Try converting your PostedDate to a native Date and then just pass that to `timeago` http://jsfiddle.net/au8bq5jx/

Comment: @RoyJ i didn't get where to convert posted date to native date ???

Comment: @Cerbrus i dont have any idea of moment.js. i have just seen the website and some syntax of relative time was showing there. that something what i needed so how to use that after installing the package. Confusion is syntax are diff for year ago, for month ago , for one day ago. any example would be of great help to me

Comment: @duke I don't know what your posted date looks like.

Comment: should i show u date saved in database or should i debug it and show u date returned to view model from database. I think may be it is format error @RoyJ

Comment: Show the data that the viewmodel receives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the date format, and its parsing. You can use the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/) to

- parse the UTC date: [moment.utc(String)](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/),
- and even to format in a format similar to fuzzy [moment().fromNow()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

So you can drop the fuzzy library, and start using moment.js.

Please, see also this answer related to moment.js timezone handling which can also affect you:
[how to handle date for posting purposes in the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497842/how-to-handle-date-for-posting-purposes-in-the-server/33499195#33499195)

Comment: thnx for the reply sir. i am not getting any intellisense for moment function on view page.I have added the reference at the bottom for moment.min.js. how should this line be formatted <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: PostedDate"></span> to use moment.js with it.I have removed timeago function and now, data should reach knockout view model in json format. change it like this //self.PostedDate = getTimeAgo(data.PostedDate);
    self.PostedDate = data.PostedDate;

Comment: should it be something like this---  <script>
                                                moment().fromNow(Post.PostedDate);
                                           </script> how to insert here knockout data-bind function

Comment: thnxx for ur reply. i ahve resolved it myself. no need for moment js i will update solution soon

Comment: Even if you yourself have found a way to do it, when dealing with dates and times that should be formatted and parsed for the user, I recommend keeping the "real value" in one observable, and use a different one to fomrta/parse the value. One way to go is by using extenders. Look for ko date or number extenders, and you'll see what I mean. If you don't feel like investigating extender, at least you can use writable computed observables to parse/format the value for the user, while keeping the standard value somewhere else.

Comment: okk thnk u sir i will definitely have a look at your suggestion